# Analytical Expression of complex roots of a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Can someone give analytical expressions for the complex roots of the polynomial of the form:

$$(1+x)^n + (1+x)^m - 1,$$

where $n$ and $m$ are arbitrary integers.

Basically, I want an analytical explanation of the following region (which are the roots achieved from mathematica):

[Roots of the Polynomial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPZIw.jpg)

Comment: Any context/effort?

Comment: @Sean Please take a look at the picture I added. This picture shows the zeros of the polynomial where $m$ and $n$ are integers between 20 and 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that in general there is a closed-form for the roots in terms of $n$ and $m$, except for the easy cases where $n=m$, or one of them is zero.  For an "analytical explanation" of your plot, suppose without loss of generality that $n>m\geq 1$, and make the natural substitution $z=1+x$, so the polynomial is $z^n+z^m-1$. Then for all $\zeta$ such that $\vert \zeta\vert=1.62$, you can check that $\vert \zeta^n\vert>\vert\zeta\vert^m+1\geq \vert\zeta^m-1\vert$. Rouche's Theorem then implies all $n$ roots lie in the disc of radius $1.62$ centered at $0$. Translating back, all the roots of your polynomial are in the disc of radius $1.62$ centered at $x=-1$ in the complex plane. For specific choices of $n,m$ with $n>m$, you can make this tighter.

Also, there's always a real root between $-1$ and $0$ by the intermediate value theorem. There are no positive roots.

**Edit:** If you want an even better bound on the roots, going back to $z^n+z^m-1$, it follows from [Landau's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Landau's_inequality) that the product of the magnitudes of the roots with magnitude at least $1$ here is bounded by $\sqrt{3}$. Any nonreal root will come with a conjugate pair with the same norm, so each must have magnitude at most $3^{1/4}\approx 1.32$. You can use Descartes' Law of Signs and probably the intermediate value theorem to show there are only a couple of real roots, and they are pretty close to $0$. So Landau's inequality gives a pretty good radius on almost all of the roots.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It seems  1.62  is the most one can get using Rouche's theorem. But can you give a better bound for the radius of the circle (The picture seemed to have a lower radius)? May be using some other technologies? In this context what are the other method to show location of zeros?

Comment: @Unknown I added some more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer.